# Analytic maps $\varphi: \mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^n$ with degenerate differentials

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $B^n\subset \mathbb C^n$ be a unit ball with center $p$ . Let $\varphi: B^n\to \mathbb C^n$ be a complex analytic map such that $d\varphi$ has rank at most $n-1$ at $p$. I would like to know if there exist two distinct paths in $B^n$ starting at $p$ that are mapped to the same path in $\mathbb C^n$.

More formally, I would like to know if the following is always true.

**Question.** Is it correct that there exists two smooth paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2: [0,1]\to B^n$ such that

1) $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_2(0)=p$.

2) $\varphi(\gamma_1(t))=\varphi(\gamma_2(t))$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

3) $\gamma_1(t)\ne \gamma_2(t)$ for $t>0$.

Comment: That follows from Sard's theorem and a little bit of commutative algebra (perhaps there is a more direct proof).  Inside $B^n\times B^n$ consider the complex analytic subspace $Z=\{ (s,t)\in B^n\times B^n : \phi(s)-\phi(t)=(0,\dots,0)\}$.  This has (locally) $n$ defining equations coming from the $n$ coordinates of $\phi$.  By Sard's theorem, there is a dense open subset $U$ of $B^n$ on which $\phi$ is submersive, so $\Delta(U)$ is an open subset of $Z$ . . .

Comment: . . . Now consider the stalk $I$ of the ideal sheaf of $Z$ inside the ring $R$ of germs of holomorphic functions at $(0,...,0)\in B^n\times B^n$.  The ideal $I$ is generated by $n$ elements.  If the height of $I$ equals $n$, e.g., if $Z$ has only components of dimension $n$, then $I$ is a local complete intersection ideal.  If the diagonal is the only component of $Z$, then $R/I$ is also "generically reduced".  A generically reduced ring that is also a local complete intersection (or even just $S1$) is everywhere reduced . . .

Comment: . . . So if the diagonal is the only component of $Z$, this gives a contradiction: the Zariski tangent space of $Z$ has dimension at least $n+1$, yet it is reduced on the open subset $\Delta(U)$.  Thus, $Z$ must have another (local) irreducible component that contains the origin.  By Krull's Hauptidealsatz (applied to the Noetherian ring $R$), every component has Krull dimension $\geq n$.  So there is an analytic curve in that component.